# Simplifying $\sin^{-1}[2^{x+1}/(1+4^x)]$ to $2\tan^{-1}2^x$ does not work numerically

Tags: trigonometry, inverse

When we simplify $\sin^{-1}[2^{x+1}/(1+4^x)]$ the following answer is given $2\tan^{-1}2^x$; but when I put in $x=0.1$, the results do not coincide. How is this possible?[image][image]

Comment: Please show your simplification work. This will help others identify where something may have gone wrong.

Comment: In the future, remember that the idea of MathJax is you write `$` once, then **the entire formula**, then `$` to say it's complete. The `$` symbols are not meant to format your formula in bits and pieces.

Comment: I have attempted to add for example some punctation marks in your one sentence text...

Comment: As a matter of fact the "simplification" is wrong mathematically, not just numerically, whenever $x>0.$ Show your work and someone will probably be able to point out a step where you assumed that $x\leq 0$.

Comment: Now please see calculation

Comment: The step from $\sin^{-1}(\sin2\theta)$ to $2\theta$ (or, more simply, from $\sin^{-1}(\sin u)$ to $u$) requires constraints.

Comment: This is interesting. Maybe there's something in the part of the book outside the photograph that would redeem the calculation in the photo, but the derivative of $\sin^{-1}[2^{x+1}/(1+4^x)]$ is negative for $x >0$ and undefined for $x=0,$ contrary to what the formula for $f'(x)$ on that page says.

Comment: Unless you're assuming that most browsers correctly and automatically rotate images, isn't it less of a hassle for you to rotate the photo before posting it than for multiple users to each extract then rotate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible because $2\tan^{-1}2^x$ can range between $0$ and $\pi$ here, but by definition $\sin^{-1}[2^{x+1}/(1+4^x)]$ can only range from $0$ to $\frac {\pi}2$ here, so the equality only holds for $x\le 0$.